# Using std::begin and std::end with array with run-time size

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator

For a coding test, I have the following function:

```
static bool exists (int ints[], int size, int k)
```

The goal is to return `true` if `k` is in `ints` else return `false`.

Using the std library, one could do this:

```
static bool exists (int ints[], int size, int k) {
    return std::binary_search(std::begin(ints), std::end(ints), k);
}
```

However, `std::begin()` only works with C-style arrays if the size is known to the compiler, from what I've been able to gather. I'm not sure why that is the case though.

Is there a way to achieve what I want without writing a custom iterator to handle it? Is it even possible to write such an iterator?

Using `std::vector` instead is not an option, since I can't change the function definition. Copying the array to a `std::vector` before calling `std::binary_search()` also seems like a waste of CPU time.

Comment: Do you have to use `std::begin` and `std::end`? You can have this effect with `std::binary_search(ints, ints + size, k);`. Or with `std::array`/`std::vector`.

Comment: Wow it didn't occur to me that you could do std::binary_search(ints, ints + size, k); Thanks for the answer.

Comment: That's the way we used to do it before `std::begin` and `std::end` existed.

Comment: Array type function arguments are a big lie inherited from C. They are actually just a pointer to the first element. This is one of the reasons there is often confusion between pointers and arrays. As you've noticed `std::begin` and `std::end` don't work with pointers. But a pointer is a valid kind of iterator, so you can use pointers instead of `std::begin` and `std::end` as long as those pointers refer to a contiguous range of elements. So you can use `ints` as the `begin` iterator and `ints + size` as the `end` iterator.

Comment: also note that `std::binary_search` is only valid if `ints[]` is sorted, which you did not mention in the question.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `std::begin()` or `std::end()` as you want to because, as Andrieux pointed out in a comment, what appears to be an array-type in the function's argument-list is just a pointer. This is confirmed by the fact that the second argument to the function is the number of elements. Such an argument would not be necessary if the information needed by `std::end()` were present in `ints[]`.

As each of the first four comments that I saw at the time of this writing indicated, however, the pointer that is passed in is an iterator.  In fact, an ordinary pointer has all of the properties of a random-access iterator.

So, yes, you don't need to come up with your own kind of iterator. Just use the passed-in pointer as the commenters indicated.

```
static bool exists (int ints[], int size, int k) {
  return std::binary_search(ints, ints + size, k);
}
```

However, calling `std::binary_search()` is the right thing to do only if the elements of `ints[]` be ordered so that `std::binary_search()` will work.  You did not state that in your post.

As to whether it be possible to write an iterator like what you might want, the answer is "yes," but it is unnecessary because a pointer is already the right kind of iterator to input to `std::binary_search()`.

You are right that using `std::vector` in the body would be a waste of time.

You could have done exactly as you originally wanted if both the input-array were ordered, and the signature of the function had instead been

```
template<int size> bool exists (int (&ints)[size], int k);
```

Comment: Note that the `template<int size>` solution is great but only works if `size` is a compile-time constant.